# Can sys or system users access ANY table in database?

Tags: oracle

Can sys or system users access ANY table in oracle database, including the ones they don't have explicit grant to ?

Let's say for example I have a user : **MyUser** who have a table **MyTable**. **MyUser** didn't grant an explicit privilege to **sys** or **system** to access this table. Can **Sys** or **System** access it though ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SYS and SYSTEM users are administrative users and have the DBA role granted by default. Part of the DBA role is the `ANY TABLE` privilege which allows them to access any table within the Database. This can of course be a problem with regards to security. To address that Oracle introduced a product within the Database called [Database Vault](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DVADM/toc.htm).

Answer (score 1):

System ans Sys are administrators, they have access to any table, but if there is no public synonym on a table then these accounts have to use fully qualified name, like:

```
select *
  from HR.employees
```

or

```
select * 
  from SH.sales
```